# Resize and color SVG from CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, colors, scale

I'm using a SVG file in my page and I'm able to resize it based on container style by loading it from `<object>` tag. I need to change fill color based on a css class but I'm not able to do this. I'm able to change color only with JavaScript but sometimes it doesn't work. I load that SVG a lot of times, ~30/40 object tag with data pointing to my .svg file. So I'm wondering what is the best way to:

- Load multiple times the same SVG file
- Scale the image to fit it's container
- Change fill color from css

My attempt is:

**html:**

```html
<div class="item">
   <object class="svg_icon color_1" data="file.svg"></object>
   <object class="svg_icon color_2" data="file.svg"></object>
   <object class="svg_icon color_3" data="file.svg"></object>
</div>
```

**css:**

```css
.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.svg_icon{
    height: 40px;
}
.color_1{
    fill: red;
}
.color_2{
    fill: blue;
}
.color_3{
    fill: yellow;
}
```

I tried with `.color1 > svg` too, but it doesn't work

***EDIT***
I solved this using inline SVG:
**html:**

```html
<div class="item">
   <svg viewBox="same as svg file" class="svg_icon color_1" data="file.svg">
      <use xlink:href="file.svg#svg_id"></use>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="same as svg file" class="svg_icon color_2" data="file.svg">
      <use xlink:href="file.svg#svg_id"></use>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="same as svg file" class="svg_icon color_3" data="file.svg">
      <use xlink:href="file.svg#svg_id"></use>
   </svg>
</div>
```

**css:**

```css
.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.svg_icon{
    height: 40px;
}
.color_1{
    fill: red;
}
.color_2{
    fill: blue;
}
.color_3{
    fill: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code of how you tried to do one of the things you're asking about. Applying CSS to SVG should work fine, so it's likely how you're targeting the SVG that's at fault. If you [edit] your question to include specifics about one of your questions, it will be more likely to be reopened.

Comment: All this would be much easier if you would **use inline svg**. Please take a look at https://css-tricks.com/ They are using inline svg. You need a root svg element where you put all your icons in a defs element. This root svg element would have position absolute a very small size and you can throw it out of the window. Next you `<use>` the icons in the page where needed. An svg element with a viewBox attribute and no width and height takes the width of it's container. If the icons in the root svg element have no fill and style declared you can use css to style the `<use>` element as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Loading multiple times the same SVG file is not a problem, because the browser load it the first time and don't load it after. It is in browser cache.

With svg, you can scale all that you want. What is the purpose of your question here ?

You can change svg color with css classes like that:

```css
#mySVG {
 fill: white;
}
#mySVG.black {
 fill: black;
}
```